# Sitecore 9 XP1 Topology - Error on UpdateSolrSchema step while calling PopulatedManagedSchema.aspx

Tags: sitecore-install-framework

I'm installing Sitecore 9 XP1 Topology, and everything was going well until Content Management step where I received this error

> Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Error requesting
>   https://sitecore9-cm/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all: The remote server returned an
>   error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path .\sitecore-XP1-cm.json
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

I've found a [blog](http://sitecoreguild.blogspot.com.br/2017/11/sitecore-9-quickstarts-installing.html) talking about the same error but in his case the log said "Login Failed for user" and mine does not mention anything (at least I didn't find)

When I browse to https://sitecore9-cm I receive the following error

[image]

Comment: Do you have URL Rewrite 2.1 IIS module installed?

Comment: Just checked and I don't... installing and checking again.

Comment: @ChrisAuer looks like you were right! URL Rewrite was missing and that was the reason for the error!

Comment: Great!. I have seen that error screen many times in my life.

Comment: I am installing it in Windows10 even after all above settings, I am getting the same error. When requesting:
https://sitecore9-cm/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all: Please let me know if you have any workaround for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please make sure you have URL Rewrite IIS module installed? It is a prerequisite for Sitecore 9.

Download the IIS module - https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/installing-sitecore-9-prerequisites

- Solr 6.6.2 Microsoft
- PowerShell 5.1 or later (Included in Windows 10)
- WebAdministration module (Installed when you have configured a
  computer with IIS)
- Web Platform Installer 5.0

  - Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers (Use Web Platform Installer to install)
  - **URL Rewrite 2.1 (Use Web Platform Installer to install)**
- Microsoft SQL Server Data-Tier Application Framework (DacFx) version 2016

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error while installing Sitecore 9 Update 1. I figured out that it is due to missing ASP installation. I installed the ASP .Net 3.5 and 4.7 and gave a try. It worked for me. Please check the below image and give it a try. It might solve the issue for you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We faced the similar error while installing Sitecore 9 Update 2, because I was configuring on the new machine with first time .Net/Sitecore installation. The problem was due to missing ASP component (ASP, ASP.net 3.5 and ASP.net 4.7)
Go to > Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features
Click > Turn Window Features on or off
Navigate To > Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Application development features

ASP

Asp.net 3.5

Asp.net 4.7

[image]

And make sure, all three above option should be checked, if not checked it and click ok.
Hope, it will resolve the issue.

Comment: In our case on fresh win 10 install it has been fixed by installing asp.net using this command: dism /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45

Answer (score -2):

This error might be due to your proxy setting. To fix it, follow below steps...

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to the Tools menu and click on `Internet Options`
3. Select `Connection` tab
4. And Click on `LAN Settings` button
5. Unchecked on options and check `Automatically detect settings` option
6. Click the `Ok` button and restart your browser

Refer below image for the reference.

[image]

Now your xConnect and Sitecore applications should work.